# style all other items in list on click of first item in list

Tags: css

I am looking for a CSS solution to toggle a set of styles upon the click of the first item in a list.
That is on click of the first item in a list, all other items in that list are given display:none; but when one clicks that first item again, all those items reappear as they are given the style of display:inline;

Is there anyway to do this style toggling on items in  a list without javascript?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: css does not handle events which is what clicking on something is. However, css does have the :hover pseudo element which can be used to apply specific styles when something is hovered on, which is an event technically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With CSS? No this is not possibe. But here is perfectly solved your problem with jquery, i hope this helps:

```
<style>
    .first
    {
        display:inline;
    }
    .other
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<div class="list first"></div>
<div class="list other"></div>
<div class="list other"></div>
<div class="list other"></div>
<div class="list other"></div>

<script>
    $(".fist").click(function(){
        $(".other").fadeToggle();
    });
</script>
```

Works also with

```
<ul><li>
```

and other stuff.

Comment: Shame that CSS can not listen for the click event. Anyway, thank you very much.